# Get the column names of a table and store them in a string or var c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I was wondering how I could get the columns of a database table and store each of them in a string or string array. I have the following code but I believe it does not work. I'm using the default table that is given in asp.net. I've been able to write to this table no problem but I cannot figure out how to select from it and save the values retrieved. here is what I have in my code behind

```
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {

        string query = String.Format("SELECT column_name FROM USER_TAB_COLUMN WHERE table_name = 'TestTable'");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        columns.Text = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

the error is `Invalid object name 'USER_TAB_COLUMN'`. I've tried removing this and using `"SELECT column_name FROM TestTable"` then it complains about `column_name`. Columns is a text box by the way.

Comment: Do you really want to get the column names or the rows?

Comment: @fabianbigler I don't need the rows. I want the names of the fields. so `Table b` has fields `fName lName email Address` I would want to save each of those somewhere

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`DbDateReader.GetSchemaTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getschematable.aspx).

```
DataTable schema = null;
using (var con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (var schemaCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}
foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ColumnName={0}", col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
}
```

The column name is in the first column of every row.

---

> I am trying your method but
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connection)) is throwing type
>   or namespace could not be found

I could have sworn that i have seen `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlConnection`. So you are using SQL-Server as rdbms instead?

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    using (var schemaCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TestTable;", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = schemaCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
        {
            schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        }
    }
}
// DataTable part is the same
```

Comment: I am trying your method but `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connection))` is throwing type or namespace could not be found error. Am I missing some System.Data.(blank) here?

Comment: @Andy: Whoops! Sorry, i could have sworn that i haven seen `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlConnection`. So you are using SQL-Server as rdbms instead? Then sinply replace everything `MySql` with `Sql`, it works exatcly the same way. ;)

Comment: I tried that and the error remains? This is strange because I have `using System.Data.Sql;`

Comment: @Andy: I have tested the same code with sql-server now, edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: No error thank you! Cant see the console lol but I can figure that out :p

Comment: @Andy: Maybe i have thought that you are using `MySql` because of the tag in your question.

Comment: Quick follow up. Sorry for the mysql tag that was my mistake. Also Its working perfectly and I accomplished what I needed to. Just curious this line `col.Field<String>("ColumnName")` gets me the column names. I'm assuming this `("DataType")` gets me the type (int, varchar, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've defined it, `USER_TAB_COLUMN` is not a table or view in MySQL.

To get column names, query the `information_schema.columns` view.

e.g.

to get a list of column names that in the `foo.bar` table:

```
SELECT column_name 
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'foo'
   AND table_name = 'bar'
```

(Since the same table_name can appear in multiple databases, to ensure you will get the column names from a a single table, you'd need to specify the database the table is in. This also improves efficiency of the query, if you have lots of databases, because it limits the databases that MySQL needs to check.)

To check for columns of a table in the "current" database, you can make use of the `DATABASE()` function:

```
SELECT column_name 
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()
   AND table_name = 'bar'
```

(This would be the table referenced by `SELECT * FROM bar` from the current database connection.)

Comment: `Since the same table_name can appear in multiple databases, to get the columns in a single table, you'd need to specify the database the table is in.` Unless the Connection String already singles out a particular database.

Comment: @called2voyage: Thanks for the clarification.  I was totally unaware that a specifying a database in a MySQL connection string limited which rows were returned from the information_schema tables. I believed the rows were limited only by the privileges granted to the connected MySQL user.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it. I'm not sure if it would narrow it in that specific case.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can find the table_schema? I'm using the default database provided when you make a asp.net website

Comment: @Andy:  In the example query above, replace `'foo'` with `DATABASE()`.  (NOTE: the MySQL `DATABASE()` function will return the name of the current database. This will be either the database specified on the connection, or the database specified in the latest (successful) `USE mydatabase` statement. This is the database used for unqualified references e.g. `SELECT * FROM foo`) is really a query of the `mydatabase.foo` table, where `mydatabase` is the value returned from `SELECT DATABASE()`. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Very Simply U can do it like below code..

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (DataColumn column in table .Columns)
{
    Console.Write("Item: ");
    Console.Write(column.ColumnName);
    Console.Write(" ");
    Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get column name by using MySqlDataReader and GetSchemaTable.
Not only column name, you can access almost every information of table.

Code is also very simple and understandable.

```
string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM testTable");
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(strCon);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
conn.Close();

foreach (DataRow rdrColumn in schema.Rows)
{
    String columnName = rdrColumn[schema.Columns["ColumnName"]].ToString();
    String dataType = rdrColumn[schema.Columns["DataType"]].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to do it with MySQL database table. Similar code structure can be used for your case as well.
Basically you should run "DESC table_name" query. Then you have a table description as a resulting table. You can read dataReader and retrieve whatever information filed from the Table Description. In this example I retrieve column names of the specific DB table. Hope this will save someones time. :) Happy coding!

```
 var tableDesc = "DESC table_name";

        try
        {
            Mclient.MySqlCommand tableDescCmd = new Mclient.MySqlCommand(tableDesc, mCon);
            Mclient.MySqlDataReader tableDescDR = tableDescCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (tableDescDR.Read())
            {

                searchFields.Items.Add(tableDescDR.GetFieldValue<String>(tableDescDR.GetOrdinal("Field")));
            }

            tableDescDR.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not retrieve DB Table fields.\n" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answers here is another way. For me it works faster (not much) than alternatives with DataReader. "WHERE FALSE" tells to bring no data.

Note that there are no need to iterate through DataTable.Rows as the result DataTable already describes the target table's schema (see the DataTable.Columns), not the schema of the current DataReader results

```
DataTable GetDataTableScheme(string tableName)
{
    var table = new DataTable();

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(*[ConnectionString]*))
    using (var dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE FALSE", connection))
    {
        // Adds additional info, like auto-increment
        dataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void leavestat()
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        string query = "SELECT * FROM leaverecord";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
             listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Columns[i].ToString());
        }
            conn.Close();
    }
```