# Not getting columns of specific tables of MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am trying to fetch column details of MySQL database with following details:

- Database name = student
- Table Name = student_detail

**Code:**

```
String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];
                    // For the array, 0-member represents Catalog; 
                    // 1-member represents Schema; 
                    // 2-member represents Table Name; 3-member represents Column Name. 
                    // Now we specify the Table_Name and Column_Name of the columns what we want to get schema information.
                    //Reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366(v=vs.110).aspx
                    columnRestrictions[0] = 'student';
                    columnRestrictions[1] = 'student';
                    columnRestrictions[2] = 'student_detail'

DataTable allColumnsSchemaTable = con.GetSchema("Columns"); //giving me all columns of all tables
// not getting columns
var cols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { 'student','student' "student_detail" }).AsEnumerable().Select(col => col["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString()).ToArray();
// not getting columns
var cols = con.GetSchema("Columns", new string[] { 'student',"student_detail" }).AsEnumerable().Select(col => col["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString()).ToArray();
```

Now this is working fine but giving me all columns of all tables:

```
DataTable allColumnsSchemaTable = con.GetSchema("Columns"); //giving me all columns of all tables
```

I want to get columns of specific tables.

**Update**: In my research I found that there is nothing like schema in MySQL which is in MSSQL so in MySQL schema and database are same

Comment: This is not a correct string array. `{ 'student','student' "student_detail" }`. Strings must have qutoes `"` and between student and student_detail, there should be another comma.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Sorry that was mistake but that is not a problem

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353089/get-the-column-names-of-a-table-and-store-them-in-a-string-or-var-c-sharp-asp-ne

Comment: @Damith But what is the problem with getschema method as it is working fine in case when i dont specify any restrictions

Comment: @Learning run above code in the link and debug and check the value rerun for `reader.GetSchemaTable()` check the Schema, TableName etc with the given values in your code, are they match?

Comment: Just put the table name in index 2 and leave the other `null` or empty string. Note that you have to provide them in the array, e.g. `GetSchema(new string[] { null, null, "student_detail" }`. See [Specifying Restriction Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0)

Comment: @IvanStoev:I posted the answer may be it can help someone and thanks for the guidance

Answer (score 2):

I manage to solve this problem in following way:

I moved database position from **0th to 1st** but in case of mssql database position will be at 0th position as because there is no such concept
like schema in case of mysql

```
// For the array, 0-member represents Catalog; 
 // 1-member represents Schema; 
 // 2-member represents Table Name; 3-member represents Column Name. 
 // Now we specify the Table_Name and Column_Name of the columns what we want to get schema information.

    String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];
    columnRestrictions[1] = "student"; //database name is specified in place of schema
    columnRestrictions[2] = student_detail"
```