# Returning a list of views from MySql Database C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building a simple WPF app for my colleagues to use in order to query one of our databases.

In the UI I'm trying to allow them to select a pertinent view from which to query.
Using the answer in this question: [Get the column names of a table and store them in a string or var c# asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353089/get-the-column-names-of-a-table-and-store-them-in-a-string-or-var-c-sharp-asp-ne) I'm going to also list the columns that they will have access to within the view.

To do this, I've been looking for a way to construct a dynamically generated query based on the groundwork of the above link. I'll be changing their query to something like this:

```
string NameOfView = "View1";    
string dynamicQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + NameOfView;
MySqlCommand(dynamicQuery, connection);
```

In essence I want to know what possible permutations View1 could be for the particular MySql connection.